# Is there any Arduino Virtual Simulator for Desktop PC?

Tags: serial-port, arduino, virtual, robotics

If I dont have any [arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) device, is it possible to simulate code virtually in my Desktop PC?
That means I want test my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is [simuino](http://web.simuino.com/) this is free
and [Virtual Breadbord](http://www.virtualbreadboard.com/) paid